# Cannot destructure property 'MapContainer' of 'reactLeaflet' as it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a React functional component that has a react-leaflet map being rendered on the server-side. The map shows perfectly, but when I add a click event handler function to pass to the parent component I am greeted with the error: **Cannot destructure property 'MapContainer' of 'reactLeaflet' as it is null** This is code in the child component:

```
const MyMap = (props, ref) => {
    
    const [ reactLeaflet, setReactLeaflet ] = useState(null);
    const [ position, setPosition ] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {
            // react-leaflet errors if imported server-side (with "ReferenceError: window is not defined")
            // not sure if this load can happen in parallel with leaflet.js or not
            import('react-leaflet')
                .then(leaflet => setReactLeaflet(leaflet))
                .catch(error => noticeError(null, levels.error, error, "react-leaflet failed to load"));
        };

        loadData();
    }, []);


    const {
        MapContainer,
        Marker,
        Popup,
        TileLayer,
        useMapEvents,
    } = reactLeaflet;

    const HandleClickMap = (e) =>{

        const currMap = useMapEvents({ 
            click() {
                currMap.locate();
            },
            locationfound(e) {
                setPosition(e.latlng);
                currMap.flyTo(e.latlng, currMap.getZoom());
            },
        });

        return position === null ? null : ( <Marker position={position}></Marker> );
        
    };

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        HandleClickMap,
    }));



    if (!reactLeaflet) {
        return <LeafletCss />;
    }


    return <>
        <LeafletCss />
        <MapContainer
            center={{ lat: 0, lng: 0 }}
            zoom={13}
            ref={ref}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            className={style.mapContainer}
        >
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            />
            <HandleClickMap />
        </MapContainer>
    </>;
};

export default forwardRef(MyMap);
```

This problem happened when I added in the **useImperativeHandle** hook. Any insight into why is appreciated.

Comment: `const [ reactLeaflet, setReactLeaflet ] = useState(null);` Yeah, you set it to null... error is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: @CertainPerformance removing null just creates another string of errors: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'MapContainer' of 'reactLeaflet' as it is undefined.

Comment: You cannot extract properties from values that aren't defined yet.

Comment: Moving `if (!reactLeaflet) {return <LeafletCss />; }` to just after your `useEffect()` handler should prevent the error

Answer (score 2):

Check if `reactLeaflet` object has been imported before attempting to access its components

```
const MyMap = (props) => {
   const {
        MapContainer,
        Marker,
        Popup,
        TileLayer,
        useMapEvents,
    } = props.reactLeaflet;

    const [ position, setPosition ] = useState(null);

    const HandleClickMap = (e) =>{

        const currMap = useMapEvents({ 
            click() {
                currMap.locate();
            },
            locationfound(e) {
                setPosition(e.latlng);
                currMap.flyTo(e.latlng, currMap.getZoom());
            },
        });

        return position === null ? null : ( <Marker position={position}></Marker> );
        
    };

    useImperativeHandle(props.ref, () => ({
        HandleClickMap,
    }));

    return <>
        <LeafletCss />
        <MapContainer
            center={{ lat: 0, lng: 0 }}
            zoom={13}
            ref={ref}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            className={style.mapContainer}
        >
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            />
            <HandleClickMap />
        </MapContainer>
    </>;

}

const MapLoader = (props, ref) => {
    
    const [ reactLeaflet, setReactLeaflet ] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {
            import('react-leaflet')
                .then(leaflet => setReactLeaflet(leaflet))
                .catch(error => noticeError(null, levels.error, error, "react-leaflet failed to load"));
        };

        loadData();
    }, []);

    return (reactLeaflet ? 
      <MyMap reactLeaflet={reactLeaflet} ref={ref} /> : 
      <LeafletCss /> 
    );
};

export default forwardRef(MapLoader);
```

Comment: that then creates this error: React Hook "useMapEvents" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can split the map loading out of your component. I think you can only use `useMapEvents` in a React component that's a child of `<MapContainer>` so you may need to break this up further into more nested components

Comment: Thanks is this component in one file or 2 different ones?

Comment: You can separate them into different files